# SpreadsheetGear Grid: events for deleting or inserting rows or columns?

Tags: events, grid, spreadsheetgear

As the title says, is there an event for those actions like deleting a row or column, inserting a row or column, or changing text in a cell? I'd be very disappointed if there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete or insert a row or column, the [RangeChanged event](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView~RangeChanged_EV.html) of the WorkbookView class fires. For example, if you delete a column, you can see the address of the column from the RangeChangedEventArgs.

```
public void workbookView1_RangeChanged(object sender, RangeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //if column D is deleted, address = "$D:$D"
    string address = e.Range.Address
}
```

A useful event for handling text entered in a cell is the [CellEndEdit event](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView~CellEndEdit_EV.html) of the WorkbookView class which fires when a user finishes editing a cell.

```
private void workbookView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, CellEndEditEventArgs e)
{
  IRange range = e.RangeSelection;
  string entry = e.Entry;
}
```

Comment: Okay, RangeChanged event is fired a lot. But how do I know if the range is deleted or inserted? From my testing, I got the same range for deleting or inserting.

Comment: You're right, there is nothing in the RangeChanged event that will tell you whether a range is inserted or deleted. Other than knowing the state of the range before the range is changed, I don't know how you can determine the type of change. There are no range insertion or deletion events that I am aware of.